# How to disable custom event at library component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

There is a switcher component from `ux-components` library that allows several events to be processed. One of those event handlers is called `onValueChange`. 
I want to prevent the default behavior and disable that event from triggering at all.

I tried some of the js methods, such as `preventDefault()`. It seems like it won't work with custom events.

This is my component that has the `onValueChange` event.

```
<ux-switcher-field 
  (onValueChange) = "someFunc()" >
</ux-switcher-field>
```

This is the event emitter:

```js
@Output()
public onValueChange = new EventEmitter<UxValueChangeEvent<T>>();
```

And as I said, I want just to disable that event from triggering in one specific place.

Comment: So do you have access to the sources and can change them?

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov yes, but that component is used not once. So I can't change that

Comment: Can you just pass a noop function to it? I think result will be the same - no further reaction to an event.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov it seems like it's not working too. If I get it correctly - noop is a empty function, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.preventDefault() like this in template

```
<ux-switcher-field 
  (onValueChange) = "$event.preventDefault()" >
</ux-switcher-field>
```

Comment: Yea, I tried that. It's not working at all. It seems like it won't work with custom events

Comment: I tried similar thing on a small example  and it worked

Comment: It also logging ERROR TypeError: $event.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: can you share a small stackblitz with an example having the same issue as it is working for me

Comment: I would love to, really. But it's a part of a product and counts as a trade secret :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$event.stopPropagation()` to cancel the event.

The code should look as bellow:

```
<ux-switcher-field 
  (onValueChange) = "$event.stopPropagation()" >
</ux-switcher-field>
```

more details about stopPropagation you can read here:

[stopPropagation description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: It's the same error, as preventDefault() - ERROR TypeError: $event.stopPropagation is not a function